# Regex for finding substring thats starts with substring but not other subtring

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse my code to find all calls of function `t('phrase to translate')`. The regex `/(?<=t\((['"]))(.*?)(?=\s*\1\))/gi` works fine, but it also finds functions like `get('something to get')`. How can I exclude all the matches that starts not only with `t(`?

Comment: `\b` before the `t` might do the trick. It should catch any word breaks, so white space, comma, newline, etc. Not 100% it will catch `{t(...` but I think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put an end-of-word marker, `\b` in the regex before the `t`:

```js
const good = "t('phrase to translate')";
const bad = "get('something to get')";
const regex = /(?<=\bt\((['"]))(.*?)(?=\s*\1\))/gi;

console.log(good.match(regex), bad.match(regex));

// returns:
// [
//   "phrase to translate"
// ] null
```